# UV's get distort on maya

Tags: maya

First of all, let say to you I'm pretty new to Maya, and I just started to texturing.

My question is, everytime I move or resize an UV, every other adjacent UV in the plane get's distorted.

So I'm asking if there is a way to turn this "feature" off

As Johnatan asked here is the image
http://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/800x600q90/546/y1og.png

This happens with every transform, like rotation and moving as well...
Thank you for your time

Comment: Not sure if SO is the right place for the question but an image of what's happening would help

Comment: i uploaded an image already =) I think i can ask this here, since there is a Maya tag available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have *Soft Selection Mode* turned on

- You can toggle it on and off with <kbd>b</kbd>
- You can adjust the size of the falloff by holding down <kbd>b</kbd> and dragging the mouse
- You can change other settings for it by going to Tool Settings (double-click the Move tool in the toolbox, among other ways)

Soft select **off:**
[image: soft select OFF]

Soft select **on:**
[image: soft select ON]

It's a useful tool, at least when you can turn it on and off :)

Comment: Thank you so much! this is a thing that is so common that no one explains, but at least now I can control each UV individually! Thanks fo rthe tip =D